# why do we use the glasses so that a different image is seen in each eye in the binocular rivalry experiment?

Tags: neuroscience, vision

If we use the glasses so that in the right eye we see a house and on the left eye a face, we can see with a fMRI that the FFA is activated when seeing the face and the PPA activated when seeing the house. But if we did not use these glasses and just saw the house and face superimposed, how would the recording look? The recording for when you force yourself to see the house and then the face? The same as with the glasses? So what difference do the glasses basically make? Thanks in advance!

[image]

source of image: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698909000169

Comment: It would be helpful to include references/sources in your post. I would expect the source to explain the purpose of this experiment, what have you read and why does that explanation not make sense to you? I'm not really understanding what you mean by "just saw the house and face superimposed"; how would that happen, exactly, without the glasses?

Comment: I included an image into the post! That is what I mean by seeing the house and face without glasses, so you would see them simultaneously and only one of them if you force your brain to perceive only one of them.

Comment: How would that show binocular rivalry?

Comment: aah wait, so binocular rivalry is created when your brain perceives two alternative images because both eyes SIMULTANEOUSLY see something different.  Without the glasses, you would be able to control what to look at, there is no alternation of images as one image is perceived at a time. If we see the face by the right eye, I assume the right temporal retinal fibres do not participate for perceiving the image because that is for the left visual field, right? And so this means right temporal and left nasal retinal fibres do not get involved in this binocular rivalry experiment with glasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend backing up a bit and looking at the big picture. What's the whole point of these experiments?

[Binocular rivalry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binocular_rivalry) is an observation, like seeing that the sky is blue is an observation. That is, when you present two incompatible images to the two eyes, you typically perceive one or the other, not a combination: that's the observation/phenomenon.

The next step is to use this observation to try to understand more about how the brain processes information. Not necessarily just to understand this weird binocular rivalry paradigm, which isn't something that would normally occur out in the world (without someone messing around with some goggles your eyes are generally going to be viewing the same world, not different ones), but to ask how this little "malfunction" gives insight into how the brain processes information in general.

An fMRI experiment that shows the FFA is activated when someone perceives a face, and PPA activated when someone perceives a house, tells you something about the relationship between PPA and FFA and perception. The context of binocular rivalry presents an interesting and very useful control experiment.

Let's set binocular rivalry aside for a moment and just consider looking at pictures of houses and faces. Again, you'll see differences in FFA versus PPA with houses versus faces, great. But, you'll also see differences at the retina. In fact, if you had some machine learning algorithm, you could definitely use responses from the retina directly to figure out if someone is looking at a house or a face: it's really the same problem as doing it from a camera image. So, this test isn't really measuring anything about what's going on "inside your head"/inside the mind/conscious perception, its just measuring a biological representation of the outside world.

Now consider binocular rivalry: you're presenting a constant face image to one eye, a constant house image to the other eye. At the level of the retina (and, to some extent, in early visual processing areas in the brain like LGN and V1), you can expect exactly the same activity no matter what the perception is: the experiment lets you dissociate what is different because the perception is different from what is different when the outside stimulus is different. The outside stimulus stays the same, yet the *perception* changes, and the perception changes are associated with changes in activity in particular brain regions. That provides some evidence that perception of objects (rather than mere signal processing of visual patterns) involves brain regions like the FFA and PPA.